# Handling Ref in React Functional Component written in TypeScript: Element is not assignable error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref, create-ref

I am running into possibly a syntax problem with my following code. `elementRef` as updated towards the bottom of the code in a `div` with the `ref` attr, linting is telling me:

```
let elementRef: React.MutableRefObject<null>
Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<null>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<null>'.ts(2322)
```

I am apparently not understanding how createRef is intended to work and would appreciate some guidance.

FC Code:

```
interface VerticalNavExpansionPanelInterface {
    location: any;
    item: any;
    key: any;
    children: any;
  }

  const VerticalNavExpansionPanel: React.FC<VerticalNavExpansionPanelInterface> = ({ location, item, key, children }) => {
    const [collapsed, toggleCollapsed] = React.useState(true)

    let history = useHistory();
    //let elementRef = React.createRef();
    let elementRef = React.useRef(null);

    let componentHeight = 0;

    const handleClick = () => {
      toggleCollapsed(!collapsed);
    };

    const calcaulateHeight = (node: any) => {
      if (node.name !== "child") {
        for (let child of node.children) {
          calcaulateHeight(child);
        }
      }
      componentHeight += node.clientHeight;
      return;
    };
    React.useEffect(() => {
      calcaulateHeight(elementRef);
      // // OPEN DROPDOWN IF CHILD IS ACTIVE
      for (let child of elementRef.children) {
        if (child.getAttribute("href") === location.pathname) {
          toggleCollapsed(false);
        }
      }
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <TouchRipple
          className="nav-item flex-middle h-48 w-100"
          onClick={() => handleClick()}
        >
          <div>
            <Icon className="text-middle item-icon">{item.icon}</Icon>
            <span className="text-middle pl-20 item-text">{item.name}</span>
          </div>
          {item.badge && (
            <div className={`badge bg-${item.badge.color}`}>{item.badge.value}</div>
          )}
          <div
            className={
              collapsed
                ? classes.collapseIcon + " item-arrow"
                : classes.expandIcon + " item-arrow"
            }
          >
            <Icon className="text-middle">chevron_right</Icon>
          </div>
        </TouchRipple>

        <div
          ref={(el) => (elementRef = el)}
          className={"submenu"}
          style={
            collapsed
              ? { maxHeight: "0px" }
              : { maxHeight: componentHeight + "px" }
          }
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an explicit type to `useRef` that is the type of the HTML tag that want to have a reference to:

```
const elementRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

---

Also, note that the only valid property of a ref is `current` which retrieves the current value of the ref. So you probably want to change:

```
elementRef.children
```

to:

```
elementRef.current.children
```

And make a similar change everywhere you access a property of the ref.